# How to disable business hours in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to incorporate FullCallendar in one of our application to show events. Now I am facing a problem with business hours. In the month view it is showing wrong end date (one day less than actual) if any event ends before 9 am. So for example, say I have two following events

```
Event 1: Start date&time : 2016-11-09T10:00, End date&time : 2016-11-20T17:30

Event 2: Start date&time : 2016-11-09T10:00, End date&time : 2016-11-20T08:30
```

In this case in the month view, Event 1 is covering all dates from 9 to 20, however Event 2 is covering dates from 9 to 19.

I tried in Google with this issue and found following link

[How to set the business hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834349/how-to-set-the-business-hours-for-fullcalender-v2-2-5)

But it does not solved the issue. I want to disable business hours. I tried by setting it false. But nothing happen.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `nextDayThreshold` option in full calendar

```
nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00'
```

for more information:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers to multiple questions.