# Full calendar : one day shift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I use Fullcalendar to render data from google calendar with google calendar API. For the test, I don't use google API feed.
My problem is:

For the same date at 08:00 AM I have a selection of 2 days

[image]

```
 events : [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: '2017-09-04T08:00:00+02:00',
                end: '2017-09-06T08:00:00+02:00'
            }
        ],
```

And for 09:00 AM, I have my correct selection of 3 days

[image]

```
events : [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: '2017-09-04T09:00:00+02:00',
                end: '2017-09-06T09:00:00+02:00'
            }
        ],
```

I've make the same test on google calendar and I get a selection of 3 days for the same 2 hours begin - end.

Somebody can help me?

This is my basic config of fullcalendar:

```
 editable: true,
 height: 500,
 firstDay: 1,
 selectable: true,
```

Comment: This is a shot-in-the-dark, but my instinct is to say this has got something do do with only displaying **business hours** on the calendar? I took a very quick glance at the source code and found [something about this in the CSS styling](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails/blob/fc1353b64e424f379985555eae88834a72349b4d/vendor/assets/stylesheets/fullcalendar.css#L1058-L1061), too.

Comment: i.e. If the event ends before 9am (or however else you initialised it?) then perhaps it's not being displayed for that day?

Comment: I've not initialized nothing. I just want the same behavior as google calendar... You think that there is an option to disable business hours?

Comment: I found this option but it is set to false by default and I've not configure it...

Comment: Is your calendar being rendered in a `.fc-business-container`, as I highlighted above? Can you please try to confirm whether or not my hunch was right?

Comment: In fact, here we go -- another quick google and I found this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/ -- So you could just do `nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00'`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable business hours in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522024/how-to-disable-business-hours-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: It's not in a .fc-business-container but in a .fc-unthemed fc-ltr. I've set the nextDayThreshold to "00:00:00" and it works! Thank you very much!